# Does OpenVPN encrypt my traffic between my computer and VPN server?

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

I set up my own VPN by installing OpenVPN on a Ubuntu server, then I download `client.ovpn` file from Ubuntu server to my Windows laptop. And then, I import that `client.ovpn` to `OpenVPN GUI` app on Windows and finally, I connect to my Ubuntu VPN server and everything work fine.

I installed OpenVPN on Ubuntu server using this instruction: https://github.com/angristan/openvpn-install

So i think traffic flow will be like this:

```
My computer (browser,...) --> Ubuntu OpenVPN server --> Internet.
```

My question is does OpenVPN GUI encrypt traffic between my computer to Ubuntu OpenVPN server?

And as always, thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the point of OpenVPN is that the traffic is encrypted (unless you disable all security in the server's config file) between the client (your Windows laptop) and the Ubuntu Server.  Your traffic to the internet is not encrypted though.  You'd best use Tor if you want to hide your IP Address online.

Comment: Thank you so much for your great answer.

Answer (score 2):

ISPs as of 2020 use deep pack sniffers which although can't read the information can easily log source and destination. They do that to prioritize traffic. If you are able to change your IP on the fly that might buy you a couple of hours but in the end they choose how much and how long you can maintain that connection at the speed you want no matter what is advertised. If you have large files to move and are not happy with the speed your best bet is to experiment with different times of the day. ISP leaves that option open for those who move a lot of data. My window of opportunity is between 4:00 am and noon. That could vary based on geographic location. Streaming services have tasked servers quite a bit in the last decade.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your information, it could help so many people.